# Python Append Dictionary in Dictionary Value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using shelve module and I have some categories let's say 'A',B,'C' and I have some article which belong those categories I am making a dictionary key is article name value is any number and in shelve module when I append it says:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

here is my code

```
indexDb = shelve.open('index.db')
if indexDb.has_key(linko.text.encode('UTF-8')):
    indexDb.setdefault(linko.text.encode('UTF-8'),{}).append(allArticle)
else:
    indexDb[linko.text.encode('UTF-8')] = allArticle
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: That's because you don't append to a dictionary.  There is no `append()` method.  A dictionary is unordered, so the whole idea of "append" misses the point of a dictionary.  It is not a list.  If you want to add a key then just assign it.

Comment: yeah I just update instead of update I am using append

Comment: Maybe you should change `{}` with `[]` in `setdefault`, and `append` with `extend`. Btw, your code doesn't make sense because if `indexDb.has_key` returns `True`, then you don't even have to use `setdefault` because key already exists in the dict.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with the `append()`?

Comment: @cdarke I have lot's of article and this article belong to a category so I have to make a dictionary structure like {A:{Article:1,Article:2},{B:{Article:3}}}

Comment: You CANNOT append to a dictionary, you add.  Do your mean:  `{A:[{Article:1},{Article:2}]}` ?  Probably better as `{A:{Article:[1,2]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `{}` with `[]`, and `.append()` with `.extend()` when calling `setdefault` method.

```
indexDb.setdefault(linko.text.encode('UTF-8'), []).extend(allArticle)
```

Btw, you don't have to check if key exists because `.setdefault()` returns the key value available in the dictionary and if given key is not available then it will return provided default value which is the empty list.

Thus, you might want to update your code as follows:

```
indexDb = shelve.open('index.db')
indexDb.setdefault(linko.text.encode('UTF-8'), []).extend(allArticle)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is not append, but you can add an entire dict as below:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
dict2 = {'c':3, 'd':4}
dict3 = dict1.append(dict2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
dict1['dict2'] = dict2
dict1
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'dict2': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}
```

Perhaps you meant that you want to add each key from dict2 to dict1. In that case the command will be,

```
for key in dict2:
    dict1[key] = dict2[key]

dict1
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```